# How do I take Someone's name in Python and create a file to write to with that name?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-input

I am a bit new to Python, and trying to do something simple I'm sure. I want to ask someone their name as the initial raw_input and then I want that name to be used to create a file. This is so that any additional raw_input taken from that user it gets recorded to that file.

```
raw_input("What is your name?")
file = open("newfile.txt", "w")
```

I have the above code that will create a file called newfile.txt, but how can I make it so that the requested name will be used as the file name?
Thank you!

```
file = open("user.txt", "w")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the name in a variable and use it :

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?")
file = open(name+".txt", "w") 
...
file.close()
```

Comment: This looks reasonable to me.

Comment: Hey this is perfect. Thank you. using the (variable+"" was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Following should work -

```
user_input = raw_input("What is your name?")  # Get user's input in a variable
fname = user_input + '.txt'   # Generate a filename using that input
f = open(fname, "w")   # Create a file with that filename
f.write('')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

> how can I make it so that the requested name will be used as the file name?

Easy, simply take the variable returned by `raw_input` (the string entered by the user), and pass this into the `open` function. The string entered by the user will be used to create the filename:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?")
file = open(name, "w")
```

> any additional raw_input taken from that user it gets recorded to that file.

Now use the `write` function to insert any new data from the user into the file:

```
content = raw_input("Enter file content:")
file.write(content)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way without putting `raw_input`'s return value to a variable is to use its return value directly.

`file = open(raw_input("What is your name?") + '.txt', 'w')`